# What is the preferred way to add relations between users in Plone?

Tags: python, plone, zope

I'm making a social networking site powered by Plone and would like to set up relationships between users (friends, followers, etc.).

How can I achieve this in Plone 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046470/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-add-relations-between-users-in-plone/8047828#8047828)

I was actually thinking of using ACL Group and reference mechanism when I asking the question.
This would help permissions and sharing.

- With each relationship, create a group for each user (UserA's Friends)
- When user is created >

  - Create user groups >

    - Create references between user and groups using reference_catalog (which I don't know how to or is it even possible)
    - Add localroles for new groups on user's folder (relation-roles map can be config via a controlpanel)
- When relationship is created -> Create new groups for all users (would take time, but will be rarely used)
- Add/remove relationship -> Add/remove user from related groups

UPDATE: It seems that almost all that I need is implemented via [plone.app.relations](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.relations) package.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using [annotations](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/archetypes/appendix-practicals/b-org-creating-content-types-the-plone-2.5-way/annotations) and creating multiple trees. For ex.:

```
import BTrees
from zope import annotation

FOLLOWERS_KEY = "my.product.followers"
FOLLOWS_KEY = "my.product.follows"
FRIENDS_KEY = "my.product.friends"

portal = self.context.portal_url.getPortalObject()
annotations = annotation.interfaces.IAnnotations(portal)

if not annotations.get(FOLLOWERS_KEY, None):
    annotations[FOLLOWERS_KEY] = BTrees.IIBTree.IITreeSet()
if not annotations.get(FOLLOWS_KEY, None):
    annotations[FOLLOWS_KEY] = BTrees.IIBTree.IITreeSet()
if not annotations.get(FRIENDS_KEY, None):
    annotations[FRIENDS_KEY] = BTrees.IIBTree.IITreeSet()

followers = annotation.get(FOLLOWERS_KEY)
follows = annotation.get(FOLLOWS_KEY)
friends = annotation.get(FRIENDS_KEY)
```

Comment: With IIBTrees, the assumption is that you would use integer keys?  How would this map to a specific user (on both ends of the index)?  I might suggest using OOBTree instances for your annotation objects instead of IIBTree instances.  I strongly suggest using tuple of ('namespace', 'id') for your human/user/principal identifiers, ex: follows = {('email', 'me@example.com'):[('member', 'sdupton'),].  Also: keep in mind that relations like "follows" are not symmetric (I follow you, not always likewise); should you need an index for the other direction ('followed_by'), add one.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. IIBTree was just an example, my point was the use of annotations. Definitely OOBTrees are more appropriate.